# Please welcome your newest pro tem moderator

Tags: discussion, moderation

I'm Pops, a Community Manager at Stack Exchange. As many of you know, one of your pro tem moderators recently left the team. I'm happy to announce that a great new pro tem mod has stepped up to fill the vacancy:

[image: AJ]

Some of you may recognize AJ from, among other places, our Sound and Video sites. Please join me in welcoming your new mod!

Comment: Welcome to the moderator team, AJ!

Comment: Welcome to the team, AJ!

Comment: Thank you.  I'll try not to break anything too badly.

Comment: @AJHenderson congrats!  An excellent choice.

Comment: Congratulations!